# How can view the changes of a constantly updating variable that is inserted into a text box

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I want to create a textbox that allows me to show messages that are constantly being updated. However, with my below code it only shows the first loaded message in the variable msg. How can I fix this?

```
import tkinter
import threading
import time

global msg

def gui():
    root = tkinter.Tk()

    box = tkinter.Text(width=90, height=30, font=("Lucida Console", 10))
    box.pack(pady=20)
    box.insert(tkinter.END, msg) #this updated msg should be shown

    box.configure(state=tkinter.DISABLED)
    root.mainloop()

def loop():
    global msg
    for x in range(100):
        msg = str(x)
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = threading.Thread(target=gui)
    p2 = threading.Thread(target=loop)

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You couldn't change the text when the config of the `Text` widget is `disabled`.
2. In your code, `insert(tkinter.END, msg)` would only insert the text only once.You could use `.after` to insert the text each time.(If you didn't want to use insert method in the `.after` , you could bind a `StringVar` for your `box`.)

To fix those issues, try this:

```
import tkinter
import threading
import time
global msg

def gui():
    def insert():
        global msg
        box.configure(state=tkinter.NORMAL)
        box.insert(tkinter.END, msg)
        box.configure(state=tkinter.DISABLED)
        root.after(1000, insert)

    root = tkinter.Tk()

    box = tkinter.Text(width=90, height=30, font=("Lucida Console", 10))
    box.pack(pady=20)
    insert()

    root.mainloop()

def loop():
    global msg
    for x in range(100):
        msg = str(x)
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = threading.Thread(target=gui)
    p2 = threading.Thread(target=loop)

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
```

I don't recommend you use a global variable `msg` though.You may could consider to use a thread queue.